# Linking a border image

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if its possible to turn your border image into a link but if so, could someone please tell me how to do it? I looked it up online and on w3 schools but still couldn't find anything on how to turn my border images into a link.

Comment: What do you mean by "border image"? (and W3Schools is _not authoritative_. You should use authoritative sources like W3 and WHATWG specs, or browser vendor resources like MDN and Google's Web.dev)

Answer (score -1):

Border-image property is linked to an element if that element is a link then border-image will also behave like a link.
I have come up with a work around which works exactly the same way you want

1 parent div and two children
one children div will behave as border image
other will behave as element

https://codepen.io/thisiskamaljoshi/pen/BaMJMjX

```css
*,::after,::before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.outbox {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.text {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.border-imgBox {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Strawberrythief.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="outbox">
        <a class="border-imgBox" href="https://www.w3schools.com/">

        </a>
        <div class="text">
    
        </div>
</div>
```